# Who owns a mineral deposit that spans across multiple properties

Tags: united-states, property, mineral-rights

In the US, if a mineral (oil/gas) field/reserve is found and it spans across multiple private properties, how is the ownership of the product divided among these properties? (assuming owners have mineral rights for the properties)

Comment: It's a first come first served sort of thing for oil and gas.